# modifying hive tez container size from IBM datastage with JDBC connector takes too long

Tags: jdbc, hive, hadoop-yarn, datastage, apache-tez

In a mapr cluster using yarn and tez engine, we need to query hive data from datastage using jdbc connector. In some cases we need to increase tez container size due to data size. We do that in before sql statement in a parallel job, and then we query data in main job statement.

The problem is the before sql statement `SET hive.tez.container.size=3000` is taking hours, but the query to data is running fine (few seconds).

Could it be related to how busy is the cluster at that time? many jobs in the queue??
Don't think so because it always crashes in set statement, but never in select statement.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tez makes us of long lived a Yarn Application, that are reused between queries for faster feedback etc.

However, that means that the first query you make will cause it to allocate a Yarn container. If the cluster/Yarn queue is full, then you have to spend time waiting for even simple meta data statements. The statements after that will however be faster.

Could it be that?
Can you check in Yarn Resourcemanager what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use IBM provided Hive JDBC driver and Hive Connector stage which allows to set Hive parameters via built-in stage property.

When a DataStage job runs slow, it could be for several reasons, from what you are saying, setting hive.tez.container.size=3000 in before sql statement is what taking hours, I would suggest to look on Hive DB side while running DataStage job.

If you are not using IBM provided Hive JDBC driver, then it's better to engage official support of 3rd party Hive JDBC driver to enable JDBC driver tracing.